# Are the following q-Genocchi numbers known?

Tags: co.combinatorics, q-identities, reference-request, q-analogs

The sequence of Genocchi numbers
${({G_{2n}})_{n \ge 0}}=$   $(0,1,1,3,17,155,2073,...)$

can be defined by the generating function
$z\frac{{1 - {e^z}}}{{1 + {e^z}}} = \sum {{{( - 1)}^n}{G_{2n}}\frac{{{z^{2n}}}}{{(2n)!}}} .$

Many different q-analogs of these numbers have been studied. 
Does anyone know if the following q-analog ${({G_{2n}(q)})_{n \ge 0}}$ is known? It is intimately related with q-Chebyshev polynomials.

Let $(a;q)_n=(1-a)(1-qa) \cdots (1-q^{n-1}a)$, $[n]=1+q+\cdots+q^{n-1}$ and $[n]!=[1][2] \cdots[n].$

The q-analog can defined by the generating function

$\sum\limits_{n \ge 1} {\frac{{{{( - 1)}^{n - 1}}{G_{2n}}(q){{( - q;q)}_{2n - 1}}}}{{[2n]!}}} {z^{2n}} = $

$\sum\limits_{n \ge 1} {\frac{{{{( - q;q)}_{2n - 1}}}}{{[2n]!}}} {z^{2n}} $ 
divided by

$\sum\limits_{n \ge 0} {\frac{{{{( - q;q)}_{2n}}}}{{[2n + 1]!}}} {z^{2n}}.$

Comment: Is this the same as the q-analog you get by rewriting $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} (-1)^k {n \choose 2k}G_{2n-k} = 0$ to a relation involving q-binomial coefficients?

Comment: The corresponding Seidel identity is

$$\sum{(-1)^k}q^{\binom{2k}{2}} {n\brack{2k}}{{(-q^{n-2k+1};q)_{2k}}}/ {{(-q^{2n-2k};q)_{2k}}}{G_{2n-2k}}(q) =[n=1].$$


Comment: In the mean time I have seen that these q-Genocchi numbers are  related to the usual  $q-$tangent numbers ${T_{2n - 1}}(q)$  by

${(- q;q)_ {2n - 1}} {G_{2n}}(q) = [2n] {T_{2n - 1}}(q).$


Answer (score 1):

Different definitions of the q-Genocchi numbers and polynomials have been studied by many mathematicians for a long time, for instance: T. Kim, L. C. Jang, C. S. Ryoo, Y. Simsek, S. Araci, H. Jolany,...etc. So that, the readers can refer to the link: http://www.hindawi.com/journals/jfsa/2012/214961/